# Cannot GET /store.html

Tags: node.js

Cannot GET /store.html is the error I'm getting I'm trying to solve this error in node.js

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    require('dotenv').config()
  }

  const stripeSecretKey = process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
  const stripePublicKey = process.env.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY

  const express = require('express')
  const app = express()
  const fs = require('fs')
  const stripe = require('stripe')(stripeSecretKey)

  app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
  app.use(express.json())
  app.use(express.static('public'))

  app.get("/store", function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('items.json', function(error, data) {
      if (error) {
        res.status(500).end()
      } else {
        res.render('store.ejs', {
          stripePublicKey: stripePublicKey,
          items: JSON.parse(data)
        })
      }
    })
  })
```

Here's my working environment:

[image: Working Environment]

Comment: Which URL are you trying to hit, can you post that?

Comment: Please provide more info, where do you put those html, how your project setup. Or if you can try to made repository with reproducible error, someone will try and answer your problem

Comment: store.html is the url I'm trying to hit /store is pointing to an ejs file